# Google Adsense DotNet API 1.4 Cannot resolve reference assemblies

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-api-dotnet-client

It is a windows phone project and it was working fine until I taught to implement the Payment Reports in it and upgraded to the 1.4 now I added the reference using the nuget package found here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AdSense.v1_4/ chnaged the v1_3 to v1_4 and now I keep getting this error.

> Error  1   Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.7.0.24060, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

I tried uninstalling the Nuget Package from the Nuget Manager completely and then Installed v1_3 again but now even this has stopped working...please can you tell me where did I go wrong?? and how to fix this issue now...

Comment: After uninstalling and installing again v1_3, did you try to clean and build again? And please also check if you get the error in a C# project as well.

Comment: @peleyal I tried a clean build...i tried creating the whole thing in C# the authentication goes well but when I try using an Report the error comes in...now this is happening with both the v1_3 and v1_4 coz I uninstalled v3 and installed it again from nuget the error comes for both now...